# Unable to Delete Managed Property (Error Code 11) - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, managed-property, delete, crawled-property

I have managed property created with PowerShell using schema. Now I don't want to have that property anymore, so for that I am simply going in Office 365 admin center site and deleting the managed property from the managed property list using context menu, but it gave me following error:

> There was a problem deleting the managed property with name MyCustomProperty. Error code: 11.

[image]

I have checked that, the property doesn't have mapping anymore, crawled property is not associated with it, too. Does any one have encountered this error?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend opening a ticket with Microsoft about this in your Office 365 portal.